# Algorithm for a running harmonic mean?

Tags: algorithm, mean

I am trying to figure out how to write a running harmonic mean, that is: a harmonic mean that updates at each iteration.
It is easy to do it with the arithmetic mean...but I am struggling a lot on this one :/ any help is more than welcome :)

For the benefit of others if you can provide a pseudocode it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harmonic mean is defined as:

```
mean = n / (sum for all xi (1/xi))
```

So if you want to add another entry to the mean, you have to adapt the sum. The easiest way is to save the temporary sum across iterations. If that's not possible, you can calculate the sum from the mean and the number of entries:

```
sum = n / mean
```

Then adapt the sum (by adding and removing entries)

```
sum += 1 / newEntry
sum -= 1 / removedEntry
n += 0     in this case because one item is added and one removed
```

And re-calculate the mean:

```
mean = n / sum
```

Comment: The same sort of procedure works for the geometric mean and root-mean-square.